# jQuery validation script correction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have made a jQuery validation script to validate two `input` elements in my html.

```js
$(function() {
  function requiredValidation(txt) {
    txt = $(txt);
    var errorblock = '<span class="error-message">Please enter a valid input</span>';
    var isValid = true;
    if (jQuery.trim(txt.val()) == '' || jQuery.trim(txt.val()) == txt[0].defaultValue ||     jQuery.trim(txt.val()) == txt.attr('title')) {
      isValid = false;
      txt.addClass("error");
      txt.parent().append(errorblock);
      txt.val(txt.attr('title'));
    } else {
      txt.removeClass("error");
      txt.parent().remove(errorblock);
    }
    return isValid;
  }

  $(".newBtn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!requiredValidation(".rqvalidate")) {
      $(".rqvalidate").focus();
      return;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input  type="text" value="aks"  class="rqvalidate"/></p> <p>
<input type="text" value="aks@asd.com"  class="emailfield rqvalidate"/></p>
<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Gem ændringer"  class="newBtn"/>
```

This script works for single element, but if there are two `input` elements, validation script clears the value of both `input`.

What is the correct solution to this issue?

Note: I can validate these elements by class only. Using id of the element is out of my question, as these HTML are dynamically generated

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erVkQ/)

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the expected behaviour? If there are 5 inputs with the same class, while clicking the button on the basis of what you decide which ones is to be validated?

Comment: @TilwinJoy I wan't to validate all input which got a class "rqvalidate"

Comment: Which is exactly what is happening in the fiddle you shared as far as i can see.. both inputs have the class `rqvalidate` hence they both gets validated. Am i missing something?

Comment: @TilwinJoy Yes. I want that script to validate each input separately. IF validation for first input fails I want to apply my rules to that one only not for the second element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `txt` is a jQuery object containing set of matched elements. You need to iterate over it and check each element one by one and break the loop when an element fails validation.

You can use `each()` function to iterate over the object and return false to break the loop.

As in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/erVkQ/2/)

Update:

The following code

```
txt.parent().remove(errorblock);
```

will not work since the string errorblock is not a valid selector.

According to [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) the `remove()` method takes a string as in argument which is a valid selector...

Updted fiddle [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/erVkQ/6/)

Comment: There is some bugs in your JSFiddle solution, After each validation, it resets the value to old one

Comment: And error message is not removed when validation is success

Comment: But still there is bug. Error message is added to the first input only

Comment: @Athul "IF validation for first input fails I want to apply my rules to that one only not for the second element". you said that is what you want. the fiddle above solves the problem you mentioned in question. You should explain the question properly to get the right output. Now you're saying something else! sorry.

Comment: Problem with your solution is that, It solved the issue I asked in the question, And it created other non existing issues in the code in return. That i what I told you above.

Comment: @Athul yes, i know (there is another problem also - if you keep clicking the button it'll keep adding error messages) . SO is where the community helps to solve specific problems related to programming, not produce the entire code for a requirement... too broad questions are not encouraged - if you want a fix for all bugs related to validation, that'd mean writing a validation plugin..
The way i see it, the problems you were facing with your code are fixed, if you face another problems, try solving it, if you're still facing issues you can post another question with the available code.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are have elements with same class you will get the array of elements in the `txt` in the validation function.

So iterate them using the `for loop` or `$.each`.

Then it will show the message only to the element with wrong value.